# Problem comparing input to array using slice function

Tags: javascript, arrays, substring, slice

I am creating a search bar, that filters an array with French city names that match the input value with each keyup. I am getting some results back (using the console log), but the results are not what I expect and the IF condition I am using doesn't seem to be functioning...

Based in JavaScript and a little jQuery to get my list of cities from a text file, I've tried using `indexOf` and `match` function, but using `slice()` seems to have got me the furthest. I'm missing something somewhere to push the matched results into a new variable/array.

```
var cityArray = [];
$.get("liste.txt", function (data) {
    cityArray = data.split("\n").sort();
    console.log(cityArray);
});

$("#myInput").keyup(function () {
    var searchedWord = $(this).val();
    var counter = searchedWord.length;
    var result = [];
    console.log(searchedWord);
    // console.log(typeof searchedWord);
    // console.log(counter);
    var matchedCities = 0;
    if (counter < 3) {
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var city = cityArray.slice(0, cityArray.length);

        console.log(city[i].slice(0, searchedWord.length));
        if (city[i].slice(0, searchedWord.length) == searchedWord) {
            result.push(city[i]);
            console.log(result);
            matchedCities++;
            console.log(matchedCities);
            if (matchedCities > 5) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So I am expecting to see matched cities with the input, in the console log. BUT, the function seems to break down before then as the `result` and `matchedCities` variables don't seem to change even when I know I have typed a city that is in the list.

Comment: `slice` is not the way to go. You had the right idea with `indexOf`, but you might also look into [`includes` for strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) and [`find` for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: Thank you, @HereticMonkey. [Includes] was the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to do your search. Something like this:

```
$("#myInput").keyup(function () {
  var searchedWord = $(this).val();
  var result = cityArray.filter(c => c.toLowerCase().includes(searchedWord.toLowerCase()))
  console.log(result)
});
```

You can add the rest of the code you need but the idea is to "search" in this fashion.

Comment: Akrion - that's exacty what I need. Thank you very much. Why was I going down such a complex route when you were able to simplify it so easily? Lack of experience, I guess. thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. Remember to check the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks